# 'sed' : How to add new line after string match + 2 lines

Tags: sed

I would like add a new line after string match + 2 lines.

Here is my file :

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.2.245
netmask 255.255.254.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug eth1
#auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.240
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.2.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I want to add 'gateway 192.168.1.1' after found 'iface eth1' + 2 lines.

example: what I need to get after execute sed command

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.2.245
netmask 255.255.254.0
gateway 172.16.2.254

allow-hotplug eth1
#auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.2.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I know how to find and move 2 lines after, append line after specific string, etc. but not combine this 2 operation.
Steph

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work:

```
sed '/^iface eth1/{N;N;s/$/\ngateway 192.168.1.1/}' input.txt
```

Add the `-i` option to `sed` to save the result back to `input.txt`.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Will be using this often, as I used to do something like `line_num2=$(grep -n 'txt_to_find' targ_file.h | awk '{print $1}')` and then add to get the line number I needed! This is much more efficient.

Comment: @LevLevitsky thanks for the solution. How would you change the delimiters in this case if the text to append were a variable with slashes in it, such as a path? Thanks

Comment: @LevLevitsky UPDATE: Figured out I could just use commas for the inner s/// statement, like sed '/^iface eth1/{n;n;s,$,\n'"$PATH_VAR"',}'

Answer (score 6):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed '
/iface eth1/ {
n
n
a\gateway 192.168.1.1
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked to use 'sed' but 'Kent' is using 'awk', here is a sed script that does what you want for your example. To be more general, line 1 of the sed script can contain whatever string you want, and line 5 of the sed script can contain whatever string you want. Put the following script in a file, say x.sed, do not add any spaces or tabs.

```
    /iface eth1/{
    n
    n
    a\
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    }
```

Then run it like this on the command line.

```
    sed -f x.sed "myinputfile" > "myoutputfile"
```

Comment: Thank, i tried to do the same, like this... sed -i.bak '/^iface eth1/{n;n;a\gateway 192.168.1.1}' /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: ... without success !!?? I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add line to the end of that block, try this:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/iface eth1/{$0=$0"\ngateway 192.168.1.1"}1' file
```

with your file:

```
kent$  cat file
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.2.245
netmask 255.255.254.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug eth1
#auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.240
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.2.240
netmask 255.255.255.0

kent$  awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/iface eth1/{$0=$0"\ngateway 192.168.1.1"}1' file
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.2.245
netmask 255.255.254.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug eth1
#auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.2.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
```